# Set shipping method to all cart

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I want to set the shipping method to each cart to free shipping without choosing the shipping method, so when customer doing checkout, the shipping method will set by default to free shipping without choosing it. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto select `free shipping` on checkout page, you can override a javascript from `Magento_Checkout` module. You can achieve this by two way

---

**1] By creating your module,**

---

`Namespace/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

`Namespace/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

then create the `requirejs` to overriding the `checkout-data-resolver` js,

for this

`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': 'Namespace_Module/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
        }
    }
};
```

Now copy `checkout-data-resolver.js` from `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model` in our module with the same path `Namespace_Module/view/frontend/web/js/model`

After that, change a condition inside the function `resolveShippingRates`

From:

```
............................

     if (ratesData.length == 1) {
                    //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);

                    return;
                }

.............................
```

To

```
.................................




     var selectedShippingRate = checkoutData . getSelectedShippingRate();
        var availableRate = false;
        if (selectedShippingRate == null) { // custom code start here
            for (var i = 0;i < ratesData . length;i++){
                if (ratesData[i] . method_code == 'freeshipping') {
                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            } else { // custom code end here
            if (ratesData . length == 1) {
                //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
                selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);
                return;
            }
        }

.....................................
```

Replace `Namespace/Module/` with your `YOUR_NAMESPACE` and `YOUR_MODULENAME`

1. Activate the module : `php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Module`
2. Run a setup upgrade : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Do a static deploy : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

---

**2] By using theme**

---

Just copy `checkout-data-resolver.js` into your custom theme but make sure It path should be,

`app\design\yourvendor\yourthemename\Magento_Checkout\view\frontend\web\js\model`

After copying update `checkout-data-resolver.js` with `resolveShippingRates` function,

```
  resolveShippingRates: function (ratesData) {
               var selectedShippingRate = checkoutData . getSelectedShippingRate();
               var availableRate = false;

               if (selectedShippingRate == null) { // custom code start here
                    for (var i = 0;i < ratesData . length;i++){
                            if (ratesData[i] . method_code == 'freeshipping') {
                                selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[i]);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    } else { // custom code end here
                            if (ratesData . length == 1) {
                                    //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
                                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);
                                    return;
                            }
                    }

                if (quote.shippingMethod()) {
                    availableRate = _.find(ratesData, function (rate) {
                        return rate.carrier_code == quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code &&
                            rate.method_code == quote.shippingMethod().method_code;
                    });
                }

                if (!availableRate && selectedShippingRate) {
                    availableRate = _.find(ratesData, function (rate) {
                        return rate.carrier_code + '_' + rate.method_code === selectedShippingRate;
                    });
                }

                if (!availableRate && window.checkoutConfig.selectedShippingMethod) {
                    availableRate = true;
                    selectShippingMethodAction(window.checkoutConfig.selectedShippingMethod);
                }

                //Unset selected shipping method if not available
                if (!availableRate) {
                    selectShippingMethodAction(null);
                } else {
                    selectShippingMethodAction(availableRate);
                }
            },
```

After overriding js file into your custom theme, execute below commands,

1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy